# Merging common output from multiple JSON schema files

Tags: code-generation, nswag

I have a number of JSON schema files and have used NSwagStudio to generate the C# client classes

Each output on it's own works fine, but unfortunately there are some common elements in each json file

Is there anyway to automatically merge the output?

*... I could manually edit the various .cs files, but I want this to be process to be part of the automated build*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own little console app and use NJsonSchema/NSwag to read merge and generate code. There is no code for merging but i think it shouldnt be that complicated to implement...